# Como guardar dos campos Tipo Select Múltiple en mi tabla?

Tags: php, laravel, array

Hola gente buenas  como puedo hacer este registro?
tengo un formulario con dos inputs de tipo select multiple cada uno  guarda un arreglo el name de cada input es el sgte: (txtMaterial_id , txtMaterial_id ) estos dos son del mismo tamaño, dichos campos los quisiera guardar en un solo  registro para ello uso dos foreach para recorrer cada uno y guardarlos de esta forma ejemplo: txtMaterial_id es igual a esto¨{1,2,..} y el campo arrayfilter me trae esto ´{3,5,..} la idea es que se guarde el primer dato del array txtMaterial_id con el primer campos del segundo array (arrayfilter ), que quede de esta forma :material_id =1 , stock=3 y asi mismo con el segundo
en mi controlador lo estoy intentato guardar de esta forma pero se están duplicando los registros Como puedo mejorar mi codigo para que se guarden de la forma que deseo?.
Este es mi codigo en el controlador :

```
 if($Equipo_salida->save()){               

                foreach($request['txtMaterial_id'] as $material){
                    
                     foreach($arrayfilter as $stock){ 
                        
                        $materialSalida = array();
                        $materialSalida = new MaterialSalida();
                        $materialSalida->salida_id           =   $salida->id; 
                        $materialSalida->material_id         =   $material;  
                        $materialSalida->stock                =   $stock; 
                        $materialSalida->save();   
                    
                    }    
                    
                }
                
                
                        
                
            }
```

Por ahora solo guarda los registros duplicados de esta forma :
[image: Tabla]

Les agradezco cualquier sugerencia o ayuda ,gracias por su atención.

Este es mi formulario además de esos campos mensionados tambien guardo registros en otras tablas relacionadas , pero alli no tengo ningun tipo de problema.

```
<form  method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="formMovimiento">
                      @csrf
                      <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                          <label for="validationServer01">Responsable </label>
                          <select name="responsable" class="custom-select " id="responsable"  required>
                            @foreach ($users as $user)
                            <option value="{{ $user->id }}">{{ $user->name }}</option>
                            @endforeach                     
                          </select>
                          <div class="valid-feedback"> </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                          <label for="validationServer01">Fecha</label>
                          <input type="date" id="fecha" name="fecha" class="form-control " id="validationServer0d"  required>
                          <div class="valid-feedback"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                          <label for="validationServer0s">Destino</label>
                          <input type="text" id="destino" name="destino" class="form-control" placeholder="calle #- direcion" id="validationServer01"  required>
                          <div class="valid-feedback"></div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
                          <label for="validationServer02">Equipos a Cargar</label>
                          <select name="equipo_id[]" multiple="multiple" class="custom-select "  id="equiposearch" style="width: 100%"  required>
                            @foreach ($equipos as $user)
                            <option  value="{{ $user->id }}">{{ $user->mac }}</option>
                            @endforeach                     
                        </select> 
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                          <label for="validationServer01">Descripcion</label>
                          <textarea class="form-control" id="descripcion" name="descripcion" rows="3" placeholder="Descripcion ..."  required></textarea>
                          <div class="valid-feedback"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                          <div class="card" style="top: 30px">
                            <div class="card-header"><strong>Materiales</strong></div>
                            <div class="card-body">
                              @foreach ($materiales as $item)
                              <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-6">
                                  <div class="form-check">                        
                                   <label class="form-check-label">
                                     <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="txtMaterial_id[]" id="txtMaterial_id" value="{{$item->id}}">                                     
                                     {{$item->nombre}}
                                   </label>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-6">
                                  <span><input type="number" min="1" class="txtStocks" id="txtStocks" name="txtStocks[]" style="width: 60%" id="task" value=""></span>
                                  
                                </div>
                              </div>                              
                              @endforeach
                             
                              
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="">Soporte</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="custom-file">
                        <input name="documento" type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="documento">
                        <label name="documento" class="custom-file-label" for="">Cargar imagen</label>
                      </div>
                    
                    </div>
                  </div>
                      <div class="modal-footer">
                        
                        <a href="#" id="btAgregarMovimiento" class="btn text-light"  style="background: #3333cc">Agregar</a>
                        {{-- <button class="btn text-light" type="submit" style="background: #3333cc">Agregar</button> --}}
                        
                      </div> 
                    </form>
```

Comment: Agrega un poco mas de código. Como el del formulario para poder ayudarte. El problema puede estar allí.

Comment: okey amigo ya .

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que tienes un foreach dentro del otro (deberías utilizar un solo foreach).

Suponiendo que coincidan los indices de los dos arreglos (ya que no está clara la estructura que tienen), podrías hacer algo así:

```
<?php

foreach($request['txtMaterial_id'] as $indice => $material) {                            
    $materialSalida = new MaterialSalida();
    $materialSalida->salida_id = $salida->id; 
    $materialSalida->material_id = $material;  
    $materialSalida->stock = $arrayfilter[$indice]; 
    $materialSalida->save();    
}

?>
```